# How flutter Rect.fromLTRB and Rect.fromLTWH works?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently painting with the `CustomPainter` widget in flutter and confused about how the `Rect.fromLTWH` and `Rect.fromLTRB` renders a rectangle in a canvas visually.

Comment: whats unclear then? if you are not sure about those two `Rect` constructors you can always do `Ctrl-click` on them to see their real implementation

Comment: fromLTWH is implementing from fromLTRB under the hood. How exactly fromLTRB works

Comment: How fromLTRB works. How the left, top,right and bottom parameters are used

Comment: it simply sets 4 fileds: `double left,
double top,
double right,
double bottom` - those 4 fields describe the rect

Comment: I am not asking about the parameters i am asking about how it is used internally. Can you make a rectangle and show these parameters on it?

Comment: ok, rectangle has 4 corners: top-left corner, top-right corner, bottom-left corner and bottom-right corner - the first (top-left) is defined by `top` and `left` fields, top-right corner is defined by `top` and `right` fields, etc - something like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MDc1.png or https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/uwp/graphics-concepts/images/rect.png